# How to get Chip to display properly in dropdown widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the Dropdown widget and for the DropdownItem's I'm using the Chip widget

```
 items:options.map((f) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Chip(
                          label: Text(
                            f['option'],
                            style: TextStyle(color: hexStringToColor(f['attributes']['text']), fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                          backgroundColor:
                              hexStringToColor(f['attributes']['color']),
                        ),
                        value: f['optionid'],
                      );
                    }).toList()));
```

In the list, the chips look great:

[image]

But once selected, the chip is not fully displaying:

[image]

I've played around with a number of the style settings, but it's not clear/obvious how to get the chip to render fully? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your dropdownButton with container and set the height as you need

```
Container(
            height: 55,
            child: DropdownButton(
             
            ),
          ),
```

output:

[image]